# Best practice question - Working straight with Linq to sql classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

This is possibly a bit of a stupid question, but I am getting confused due to the ASP.NET MVC book I am currently reading...

Working with Linq-To-SQL it seems to say that it is not good practice to pass the Linq-to-SQL objects straight to the controller, but that each object should be modelled separately first and this should be passed between the controller and the repository.

Say, I have a database of products. Linq-to-SQl creates a product class for me with Name, Price and Whatnotelse properties. I could pass that straight from repository to controller and then view, but instead it seems to recommend that I use and third class, say Product_Entity, with also Name, Price etc. properties and pass that to the controller.

I fail to see the benefit of this approach, except possibly for adding attributes to the properties... But apart from that it seems to have more drawbacks than benefits. Say each product has manufacturer information as well, I don't see how I can model that easily in my third class.

Is this approach really best practice? Or did I misunderstand all that? If so, why is it bad to work straight off the linq-to-sql generated objects? And how do you deal with relationships between objects in y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The huge benefit to this other class you create is that, to use your example, it doesn't necessarily map to either a product or a manufacturer.  Think about it like this:

- Your Linq to SQL classes are meant for talking in the "data" domain.
- Your "data" classes (the ones you're having trouble with) are meant for talking in the "application" domain.

Let's take an example.  Suppose in your MVC application you wanted to show a grid of information about products.  You want to see their Name, Price (from the Product table) and their Country of Manufacture and Manufacturer name (from the Manufacturer table).  What would you name this class?  Product_Manufacturer?  What if later on you wanted to add properties from yet a third table such as product discounts?  Instead of thinking about these objects in purely the *data domain*, think about them with regard to your *application*.

So instead of Product_Manufacturer, what about calling it ProductSummaryItem?  Each property of the ProductSummaryItem class would map 1:1 with a field shown in your grid on the UI.  Your controller would perform the mapping between the information in the data domain (Product, Manufacturer) with the custom class you'd created in the application domain (ProductSummaryItem).

By doing this, you get some awesome benefits:

1) Writing your views becomes really, really simple.  All you have to do to display your data is loop through the ProductSummaryItems and wrap them in  and  tags, and you're done.   It also allows for simple aggregation.  Say for example you wanted to add a field called ProductsSoldLastYear to your ProductSummaryItem class.  You could do that very simply in your views because all it is to them is another property.

2) Since the view is trivial and there's mapping logic in the controller, it becomes much easier to test the controller's output because it's customized to what the view is going to see.

3) Since the ProductSummaryItem class only has the data it needs, your queries can potentially become much faster because they only need to query for the fields that would populate your ProductSummaryItem object, and nothing else.  This overhead can become overbearing the more data-domain objects make up your ProductSummaryItem object.

This pattern is called [Model View ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) (MVVM) and is hugely popular with MVC as well as in frameworks like WPF.

The argument against MVVM is that you have to somewhat reimplement simple classes for CRUD operations.  Fair enough, I guess, but you can use a tool like [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to help out with things like that.  I think you'll find fairly quickly, though, that using the MVVM pattern even for CRUD pays dividends, because before you know it, even with simple classes, you'll start wishing you had extra fields which can easily drive your views.

Comment: OK, if I understand you correctly I should think in terms of what I want to do with my data instead of focusing on maintaining continuity of my objects from one end of the application to the other. Sort of a translation of data from the data access point to the display point. Then that means that I potentially end up creating one (or more) classes per controller, right?

Comment: Just reading up on the MVVM reference and have a question. For simple applications, say for example the perennial nerddinner project, an MVVM is not used (at least not in the beginning, never got to the end), because it is not necessarily needed for views in which the model data is displayed pretty much as-is?

Comment: Sometimes when I'm cranking stuff out quick to play around with the shape of my views, I will do that (bind directly to the domain classes). Once I get my views pretty stable though, I usually turn them into regular viewmodels with extra properties as necessary

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't a big fan of the NerdDinner sample or Wrox book, though I really like Hanselman and Haack's other writings.  In order to get something up and running, you certainly can bind directly to your model classes for administrative CRUD ops, but it gets limiting pretty fast.